# consoleReporter won't accept mocha-teamcity-reporter as a parameter

Tags: mocha.js, mochawesome

I am trying to run mocha tests with mochawesome reporter to produce HTML report, while having a console output with mocha-teamcity-reporter.

When I specify the following parameters:

> --reporter node_modules\mochawesome --reporter-options "consoleReporter=node_modules\mocha-teamcity-reporter"

I get this:

> [mochawesome] Unknown console reporter
> 'node_modules\mocha-teamcity-reporter', defaulting to spec

Meanwhile,

> --reporter-options "consoleReporter=spec"
> works just fine.

Could you please advise on how to use the consoleReporter option?

Comment: Have you tried --reporter-options "consoleReporter=mocha-teamcity-reporter" just without prepending node_modules to teh reporter name?

Comment: yes, it didn't work